# Reset Python4Delphi engine?

Tags: delphi, python-embedding, python4delphi

I use D7 with Python4Delphi. After users have imported much of py-files, Python have all these modules cached. I need a way to reset Py engine. So that Py "forgets" all user-imported modules, and I have "clean" Python, w/out restarting the app.
How to do it?

Comment: Hmm, good luck with that. I believe you have zero chance of success. Once Python is in your process, in my experience, it's there for good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a demo showing you how to unload/reload python using P4D at https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi/tree/master/PythonForDelphi/Demos/Demo34.  The key method that (re)creates the python components and (re)loads different versions of python is shown below:

```
procedure TForm1.CreatePythonComponents;
begin
  if cbPyVersions.ItemIndex <0 then begin
    ShowMessage('No Python version is selected');
    Exit;
  end;

  // Destroy P4D components
  FreeAndNil(PythonEngine1);
  FreeAndNil(PythonType1);
  FreeAndNil(PythonModule1);

  { TPythonEngine }
  PythonEngine1 := TPythonEngine.Create(Self);
  PyVersions[cbPyVersions.ItemIndex].AssignTo(PythonEngine1);

  PythonEngine1.IO := PythonGUIInputOutput1;

  { TPythonModule }
  PythonModule1 := TPythonModule.Create(Self);

  PythonModule1.Name := 'PythonModule1';
  PythonModule1.Engine := PythonEngine1;
  PythonModule1.ModuleName := 'spam';
  with PythonModule1.Errors.Add do begin
    Name := 'PointError';
    ErrorType := etClass;
  end;
  with PythonModule1.Errors.Add do begin
    Name := 'EBadPoint';
    ErrorType := etClass;
    ParentClass.Name := 'PointError';
  end;

  { TPythonType }
  PythonType1 := TPythonType.Create(Self);

  PythonType1.Name := 'PythonType1';
  PythonType1.Engine := PythonEngine1;
  PythonType1.OnInitialization := PythonType1Initialization;
  PythonType1.TypeName := 'Point';
  PythonType1.Prefix := 'Create';
  PythonType1.Services.Basic := [bsRepr,bsStr,bsGetAttrO,bsSetAttrO];
  PythonType1.TypeFlags :=
    [tpfHaveGetCharBuffer,tpfHaveSequenceIn,tpfHaveInplaceOps, 
   tpfHaveRichCompare,tpfHaveWeakRefs,tpfHaveIter,tpfHaveClass,tpfBaseType];
  PythonType1.Module := PythonModule1;

  PythonEngine1.LoadDll;
end;
```

The demo uses the unit PythonVersions to discover installed python versions.

Answer (score 2):

It should be sufficient to destroy and re-create the `TPythonEngine` object:

```
OriginalOwner := GetPythonEngine.Owner;
GetPythonEngine.Free;
TPythonEngine.Create(OriginalOwner);
```

Destroying it calls `Py_Finalize`, which frees all memory allocated by the Python DLL.

Or, if you're just using the Python API without the VCL wrappers, you can probably just call `Py_NewInterpreter` on your `TPythonInterface` object to get a fresh execution environment without necessarily discarding everything done before.

Comment: In my experience this will not yield good results. Have you experienced success in booting Python out like that?

Comment: @david inability to load new python instances

Comment: @Rob Did you test it with TPythonModule, TPythonGuiInputOutput, are they reinited ok? I test myself later.

Comment: Haven't tested anything, @Alextp. I don't have Delphi. I only read the documentation and looked at the source code.

Comment: @Rob, sorry. I took demo05 from P4D, added button "Reset", and added ur code. I pressed "exec script", then "Reset", then "exec script", and got Access Violation at `function TPythonInterface.GetInitialized`.

Comment: You're going to have to do some debugging. It looks like the DLL will only get loaded automatically when the component comes from a DFM resource; if it's created manually, you'll have to re-call `LoadDll` yourself before any Python API functions are valid.

Comment: @Rob yes, some work needed, when I added after your code `GetPythonEngine.Initialize` I got exception "No python engine was created" inside `GetPythonEngine`

Comment: @alextp My Python embedding experience is with the raw C API and not this Delphi wrapper. I have tried very hard to remove the Python engine from the process, and then bring it back. I failed. This is not to say that I am sure it cannot be done, just that I think you should be prepared for failure. The docs suggest that this should be possible, with some caveats: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html